# LWC - Cloning Record Multiple Times

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to build a process where the user selects a clone action from a list of records along with a number.  When they do that, they are cloning that records x number of times.  I am using a parent component to clone the record selected and then passing the list to a child component to iterate over.  The issue I am having is I am trying to set an id when I clone the record.  The id for each record is ending up the same.  If I populate a 3 in the clonevalue field, all three records end up with an ID of 2.  In the code below, both the value of i and the value of gs.id are correct (as they loop, the values change from 0, 1 and 2.  However the last log with the value of the clonedGroupStructures has a 2 for all three.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

The method for cloning is below.  I have declared the following variable outside of the method as part of export:  clonedGroupStructures = [];

```
    // From Row Action Dropdown - Clone record
cloneCurrentRecord(currentRow) {

    // clear out var first in case we run multiple times
    this.clonedGroupStructures = []

  let i;
  let gs = {};
  
    // open modal box
    this.bShowModal = true;
    this.isEditForm = false;
    this.isNewForm = false
    this.isReadForm = false;
    this.isCloneForm = true;

      //loop through based on number of clones selected
    
   for (i=0; i<this.cloneValue; i++){
       // c = this.groupstructurelist[i];
      //set variables to clone field over
    
    gs.Status__c = 'Draft';
    gs.Funding_Type__c = currentRow.Funding_Type__c;
    gs.Group_Number__c = currentRow.Group_Number__c;
    gs.Section_Code__c = currentRow.Section_Code__c;
    gs.Package_Code__c = currentRow.Package_Code__c;
    gs.Effective_Date__c = currentRow.Effective_Date__c;
    gs.End_date__c = currentRow.End_Date__c;
    gs.Health_Product__c = currentRow.Health_Product__c;
    gs.prescription__c = currentRow.prescription__c;
    gs.Dental__c = currentRow.dental__c;
    gs.vision__c = currentRow.vision__c;
    gs.Rating_Category__c = currentRow.Rating_Category__c;
    gs.Coverage_Categories__c = currentRow.Coverage_Categories__c;
    gs.Prefix__c = currentRow.Prefix__c;
    gs.CDH_Status__c = currentRow.CDH_Status__c;
    gs.Description__c = currentRow.Description__c;
    gs.Account__c = currentRow.Account__c;
    gs.id = i;
    gs.Description__c = i;
    console.log('1 here is i' + i);  //this displays the iterated value correctly
    console.log('2 here is gs.id ' + gs.id);  //this displays the iterated value correctly
      //clones.push(gs);
      this.clonedGroupStructures.push(gs);  //this get populated with the same (last) value for i

    } // end of loop

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gs` has been declared outside the for-loop, so you are not creating 3 different objectes, you're just changing N times the properties of the same one and you're adding always the same object to `clonedGroupStructures`.
That's why the last values are the ones you see in every element of `clonedGroupStructures`.

```js
cloneCurrentRecord(currentRow) {
    // this.clonedGroupStructures = []; // uncomment this line if clonedGroupStructures must contains only the actual clones
    //loop through based on number of clones selected
    for (let i=0; i<this.cloneValue; i++) {
        //set variables to clone field over
        const gs = {};
        gs.Status__c = 'Draft';
        gs.Funding_Type__c = currentRow.Funding_Type__c;
        gs.id = i;
        this.clonedGroupStructures.push(gs);
    } // end of loop
    console.log('3 Here is clonedGroupStructures' + JSON.stringify(this.clonedGroupStructures));
}
```

> then passing the list to a child component to iterate over

If every time you call the `cloneCurrentRecord` the list `clonedGroupStructures` must contains only the actual clones and you don't need the old ones, please uncomment the first line of the method.

I would also suggest to declare variables using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) where possibile, otherwise [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), this way you'll declares a block-scoped local variable.

Comment: Thanks Ruben!!!  When I tred to declare inside the for look I get an error that all vars need to be declared at the start.. I will try const. thanks!!

Comment: I'm working on this this morning and I'm not getting it.  When the button is clicked I need to clone over x number of records into the array.  I tried to create a new array variable inside the method but its still uses the same value for i.  Even though the console.log shows me the value of i advancing, when it gets assigned to the array, its all the last value.

Comment: @Frank could you please update your question posting the update code. Please post the whole controller

Comment: Thanks RubenDG... I updated the code in the original post.  thanks again!!

Comment: @Frank in your code `gs` is still initialized outside the for-loop. Look [what happens](https://jsfiddle.net/egsqdkmv/) if you declare it inside the loop. If you gets an error when you try to declare it inside the for-loop, please post it here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made that harder that it should have been. I misunderstood your initial answer.  Thank you so much for helping and sticking with it!!!!